# Nested SupportMapFragment

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api-3, dictionary

I'm having the following exception while adding the Support Map Fragment

```
05-22 23:51:12.817: E/AndroidRuntime(4515): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-22 23:51:12.817: E/AndroidRuntime(4515):     at kbh.a(Unknown Source)
05-22 23:51:12.817: E/AndroidRuntime(4515):     at mbi.a(Unknown Source)
05-22 23:51:12.817: E/AndroidRuntime(4515):     at lxn.a(Unknown Source)
05-22 23:51:12.817: E/AndroidRuntime(4515):     at lxm.a(Unknown Source)
05-22 23:51:12.817: E/AndroidRuntime(4515):     at fnb.onTransact(SourceFile:107)
05-22 23:51:12.817: E/AndroidRuntime(4515):     at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:361)
05-22 23:51:12.817: E/AndroidRuntime(4515):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$a$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
05-22 23:51:12.817: E/AndroidRuntime(4515):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
05-22 23:51:12.817: E/AndroidRuntime(4515):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a$4.b(Unknown Source)
05-22 23:51:12.817: E/AndroidRuntime(4515):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
05-22 23:51:12.817: E/AndroidRuntime(4515):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
05-22 23:51:12.817: E/AndroidRuntime(4515):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
05-22 23:51:12.817: E/AndroidRuntime(4515):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
05-22 23:51:12.817: E/AndroidRuntime(4515):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
05-22 23:51:12.817: E/AndroidRuntime(4515):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
05-22 23:51:12.817: E/AndroidRuntime(4515):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
05-22 23:51:12.817: E/AndroidRuntime(4515):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
05-22 23:51:12.817: E/AndroidRuntime(4515):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:1550)
05-22 23:51:12.817: E/AndroidRuntime(4515):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:963)
05-22 23:51:12.817: E/AndroidRuntime(4515):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
05-22 23:51:12.817: E/AndroidRuntime(4515):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
05-22 23:51:12.817: E/AndroidRuntime(4515):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
05-22 23:51:12.817: E/AndroidRuntime(4515):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
05-22 23:51:12.817: E/AndroidRuntime(4515):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
05-22 23:51:12.817: E/AndroidRuntime(4515):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-22 23:51:12.817: E/AndroidRuntime(4515):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-22 23:51:12.817: E/AndroidRuntime(4515):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
05-22 23:51:12.817: E/AndroidRuntime(4515):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-22 23:51:12.817: E/AndroidRuntime(4515):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-22 23:51:12.817: E/AndroidRuntime(4515):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
05-22 23:51:12.817: E/AndroidRuntime(4515):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
05-22 23:51:12.817: E/AndroidRuntime(4515):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This happens randomly on the App. It works Ok once, twice or even three times, Then it Crashes. 
Sometimes the map appears but then it crashes.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that you can't have a nested Fragment that has a SupportMapFragment.

What I was doing it's the following:

```
MainFragment extends Fragment;
FirstChildFragment extends Fragment;
MapFragment extends Fragment;
```

The MainFragment, it's the Main Fragment that it's going to have Sub-Fragments to be shown.
The FirstChildFragment was another Fragment that's it's being held within the MainFragment, and Finally the MapFragment was held inside the FirstChildFragment, MapFragment inflated the SupportMapFragment and it sometimes worked. I changed the MapFragment to extend from SupportMapFragment, and it Worked....

Maybe my abstraction on the Fragment it's not correct. But I do use a fragments in a lot of situations it keep some of the View Logic encapsulated.

Thank you & Sorry.